# Java Callablestatement doesn't wait until .execute() ends

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am trying to get value from a Table_X . But those table values inserted by a procedure. I am calling procedure like ps.execute() and i would like to wait until it ends and get all results from Table_X , everything looks like working. But it only returns a few results from Table_X not all. So I think it doesn't wait until procedure ends. So it only returns some inserted values.

How can I fix it ?

Edit : Codes ;

```
 CallableStatement pstmt = con.prepareCall("{ ? = call  "+job.getSP()+" }");
 pstmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
 pstmt.execute();
```

Then I am calling a method

```
  Map<String,String> errors = MTRCMtdJob.GetDataControlErrors();
```

Those method gets value from Table_X

Comment: once your insert procedure complete then call then next procedure to get values .it might be working before incomplete inserts of all data

Answer (score 0):

I presume there is only one issue, the **transaction isolation level** is allowing dirty reads even before the procedure transaction is committed. I recommend that you put the reading the table section in a new transaction block by using **commit** after the procedure transaction. And also please check the transaction isolation level.